# Kivy development environment on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, python-2.7, kivy

I need to ask a question on how to set a development environment for Kivy under Windows 7. Normally i work with Kivy on Linux, but i need to develop an application for a client who uses Windows. From the Kivy documents, there are two alternatives:

1- Download and Unzip the file containing the Kivy environment plus the Python interpreter with it. I have concerns here. Will this damage my existing Python environment (2.7)? if not is it sand boxed well? Plus if i need to add other third party libraries (ex : pyodbc to run on a Kivy application on a PC) where shall they be installed ?

2- set up Kivy for existing Python environment. Another concern here : is the "unofficial" windows installer a good way to get Kivy running under Windows? and same concerns as above for the Python environment.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using kivy on windows 7 . You can use option 1 . it wont damage your current python 2.7 because you can just change the path of environment to the python interpreter which comes with kivy .

in case you need to turn back to your older python installed just change the environment variables .

Ino order to add third party libraries , most of them are already installed in kivy . for others you can find them on kivy.org :)

If you need to use for example pyQt4 or similar library you need to use different interpreter . I am also doing same stuff .In my case , I use pycharm and keep different configuration (i.e. python interpreter) for different programs .

Comment: Thank You For Your Answer @paarth batra. I understood well from you that i need to point the PATH variable on windows to the file where the Kivy python interpreter is. but in case i need to be developing another python application that is not related to Kivy(for example a pyqt4 app) should i also at each time change the PATH or can i set the path for both interpreters at the same time?for the libraries, i was not referring to libraries that are specific for a mobile development environment but to desktop libraries like pyodbc that allows you to connect to MSSQL data server

Comment: @toufikovich just edited my answer in   respect to your comment .

Comment: Changing your environment variables is not required. You only need to do that if you want to set Kivy's Python as the default Python for your system. Kivy will run perfectly well from the kivy.bat without setting environment variables.

Comment: You can install most 3rd party modules using pip from inside of Kivy's Python. The easiest way is to run the kivy.bat and issue pip commands from that console.

Comment: Aha... That's nice @brousch. I definitely prefer that I don't play with environment variables and thank you for the packages answer.I suppose pip is already installed there.thank you all.